# at - job added via PHP to queue not working

Tags: php, queue, exec, at-command

I have a small script in PHP to set some **at** jobs with **exec()**.
PHP can execute exec() and at jobs are added to the queue, because I see them on the at queue list.

```
echo "/usr/local/ffmpeg1.1/bin/ffmpeg -i '/data/html/admin.domain.com/httpdocs/raw/gym/gym_part_1.avi' -c:v libx264 -vsync 2 -strict -2 /data/html/domain.com/httpdocs/videos/galleries/gym_part_1.mp4" | at now +2 minutes
```

This simply doesn't work. It gets queued but doesn't work.
If **I run it on bash it works perfectly** with the user that i'm logged in or with apache user - by adding **sudo -u apache** before **at**.

```
echo "/usr/local/ffmpeg1.1/bin/ffmpeg -i '/data/html/admin.domain.com/httpdocs/raw/gym/gym_part_1.avi' -c:v libx264 -vsync 2 -strict -2 /data/html/domain.com/httpdocs/videos/galleries/gym_part_1.mp4" | sudo -u apache at now +2 minutes
```

Linux and at version

**linux**

```
Linux web1.com 2.6.18-400.1.1.el5 #1 SMP Thu Dec 18 00:59:53 EST 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**at**

```
at version 3.1.8
```

Comment: CAN Y0U PLEASE WRITE YOUR ACTUAL CAMMAND

Comment: echo "/usr/local/ffmpeg1.1/bin/ffmpeg -i '/data/html/admin.domain.com/httpdocs/raw/gym/gym_part_1.avi' -c:v libx264 -vsync 2 -strict -2 /data/html/domain.com/httpdocs/videos/galleries/gym_part_1.mp4" | at now +2 minutes

Comment: ARE YOU TRYING TO GET THUMBNAIL FOR VIDEO FILE IN GIVEN TIME DURATION USING LINUX COMMAND?

Comment: Sorry, the problem has nothing to do with ffmpeg but with at.

Comment: use shell_exec('command')